# Windows DFS-R conflict handling between multiple locations

Tags: windows, dfs-r, merge-replication

i´m experimenting with the DFS-Replication possibilities in Windows Server 2008 R2.

Basic structure is this

```
TestOffice 1
- Fileserver

TestOffice 2
- Fileserver

Central server location
- Fileserver
```

The three fileservers replicate their data through the DFS-R. Works well.

Lets say "Test Office 1" looses the connection to the internet.
Someone changes "File 1" on the "Test Office 1"-Fileserver.
Some minutes later someone changes "File 1" in the "Test Office 2" Location. This gets replicated to the central server.

What happens if the connection is reestablished? 
The "Test Office 2"-Version of the file wins, cause its newer, and gets replicated to "Office 1".

My question is:
What are the possibilities to either 
- block unconnected offices to change files or 
- merge the files or put them into a "Conflict"-Folder (which needs to be in the same directory as the original file, cause not all directories share the same user rights.

John

Answer (score 0):

I think peerlock might be the best solution for you:

http://www.peersoftware.com/products/peerlock/peerlock.aspx

If the internet in your offices are flaky and will disconnect a lot I do not know of any solution that will disable access while disconnected.  In that instance you may be better off with a branch cache with redirection to the main HQ than a dfs replica.

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2008/en/us/branch-cache.aspx

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I worked with peerlock, but that doesnt protect files when no connection is established. Neither does branch-cache, as that only creates a local cache. Ill continue looking.